# Working out number of permutations of lists when one (or more) values are unknown/wildcards

Tags: python, python-itertools

Working out number of permutations of lists when one (or more) values are unknown/wildcards

If I have a series of options, let's say 3 here for example. Each of the options can be 1 or 0.

I can use `itertools` to get the possible combinations.

However, if two of the options are known e.g.`[0, 1, "?"]` - how can I work out the possible remaining permutations e.g.  `(0, 1, 0), or (0, 1, 1)`?

I have far more than 3 options, so need a method that will scale (and allow more unknowns)

```py
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

input_data = []
for i in range(0,3):
    input_data.append([0,1])

print(input_data)

#get all possible combinations
result = list(itertools.product(*input_data))
print("possible permutations:", len(result))
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
possible permutations: 8
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
```

---

EDIT: 
Trying to use SimonN's suggested approach - 
Trying to replace the `?` with the list options...

If I have `[0, 1, "?", "?"]`, how can I use `[0, 1]` to replace the first instance of a `"?"` with `0` and the next with `1`?

```
def gen_options(current):
    unks = current.count("?")
    input_data = []
    for i in range(0, unks):
        input_data.append([0, 1])

    permutatons = list(itertools.product(*input_data))
    options = []
    for perm in permutatons:

        option = [perm if x == "?" else x for x in current]
        options.append(option)
    return options

test = [0, 1, "?", "?"]
options = gen_options(test)
print (options)
```

gives

```
[[0, 1, (0, 0), (0, 0)], [0, 1, (0, 1), (0, 1)], [0, 1, (1, 0), (1, 0)], [0, 1, (1, 1), (1, 1)]]
```

Comment: nb of permutation is 2^(len of array), here 2^3=8 so, what's your question ?

Comment: You do it the same way as you did the first one: multiply the freedom of each position.  In the given cases, you have 2x2x2=8 and 1x1x2 = 2.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm trying to generate the options, rather than just count them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know some of the options then you only need to work out the permutations for the unknown ones. So if you have `[0,"?",1,1,0,"?","?"]` you just need to generate all the possible permutations of three values and insert those in place of the ? characters. So in this case there will be eight options where the three ?s are replaced by the permutations you've provided in your question.

### EDIT: Here's some code

```
import itertools
from copy import copy

inp=[1,"?",1,"?",0]
output=[]

for p in itertools.product([0,1], repeat=inp.count("?")):
    working = copy(inp)
    p_list=list(p)
    for i, x in enumerate(working):
        if x == "?":
            working[i] = p_list.pop()
    output.append(working)
print(output)
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.

So if I wanted to replace the `"?`"s with the options from the list, what would be the best way to do it?

Trying to come up with a way of doing it, but this line is wrong:`option = [perm if x == "?" else x for x in current]`

How can I pass a list like `[0, 1]` and replace the first `?` in a list with `0` and the second with `1`?

Comment: Added a solution. Not super happy with it as it has more loops than I feel like it needs, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think `itertools.product` will do everything you need

```py
>>> from itertools import product
>>> x = [0,"?",1,1,0,"?","?"]
>>> a = [(0,1) if e == '?' else (e,) for e in x]
>>> print(a)
[(0,), (0, 1), (1,), (1,), (0,), (0, 1), (0, 1)]
>>> for v in product(*a): 
...    print(v)
...
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```